# Marathon on Azure Container Service - cannot scale to all nodes

Tags: azure, mesos, marathon, dcos, azure-container-service

I have setup up a VM cluster using Azure Container Service. The container orchestrator is DC/OS. There are 3 Master nodes and 3 slave agents.

I have a Docker app that I am trying to launch on my cluster using Marathon. Each time I launch, I notice that the CPU utilization of 3 nodes is always 0 i.e. the app is never scheduled on them. The other 3 nodes, on the other hand, have almost 100% CPU utilization. (As I scale the application.) At that point, the scaling stops and Marathon shows state "waiting" for resource ads from Mesos.

I don't understand why Marathon is not scheduling more containers, despite there being empty nodes when I try to scale the application.

I know that Marathon runs on the Master nodes; is it unaware of the presence of the slave agents? (Assuming that the 3 free nodes are the slaves.)

Here is the config file of the application: [pastebin-config-file](http://pastebin.com/FBpZBTDc)

How can I make full use of the machines using Marathon?

Comment: 1. The app spec you linked to is broken (incomplete and invalid), 2. Without a closer look at your setup it's hard to tell what is going on but since you claim you have 3 Masters running I can tell that you are not using the DC/OS Marketplace offering but either ACS or some other setup. 3. Since this requires more discussion to be resolved, I suggest you join chat.dcos.io and we take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Tasks are not scheduled to the masters. They are reserved for management of the cluster.